# Search Console error "uncommon download"

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I get this alert in my Google Search Consol:

**1 issue detected**

> Google has detected harmful content on some of your site’s pages. We
>   recommend that you remove it as soon as possible. Until then, browsers
>   such as Google Chrome will display a warning when users visit or
>   download certain files from your site.

**Uncommon downloads**

> Description Some or all of the downloads on this site shows "uncommon
>   download" warnings. Learn more Sample URLs N/A

My question and problem is: how can I realize/detect the mentioned file or page?
It did not refer to any specific file so I can not track this issue.

Comment: @ Amin - what you did to remove same ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known "bug"; even Google mentions that if you get one of these where no actual file is referenced, you should just request a review and ignore it (my website gets one of these every few months, just a small annoyance but no real harm).

*[Source](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-search-console-uncommon-downloads-28740.html)*